# Transferring Fallout 4 Saves (PS4)

Tags: fallout-4, ps4

So I have a pretty good save on my brothers Playstation, and I was wondering if anyone knows how to use a save from his playstation on to my account on my playstation. A problem that may occur is that my dad and I share a family account so he has the only plus account, but I can just use his account on my profile.

Ask if you need any more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a USB drive and you might be able to transfer it.

Connect the USB drive to the ps4, and then go to settings from the main menu.
You should see an option called "Application Saved Data Management". Select it.
Then you have 3 options: Saved Data in System, Saved Data in Online Storage, and Saved Data on USB. Select "Saved Data in System Storage".
From there, select "Copy to USB Storage".
Then you can choose Fallout 4 and select it for backup.

If you are wanting to transfer the save between accounts, then try relogging into your account from the ps4. If you are wanting to move your save file to a different ps4, then plug the USB into your ps4.
Go back to to the Data Management screen and this time select "Saved Data on USB Device". You should have an option that says "Copy to System Storage".

See what that does for the save file and let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much! (Edit: haven't tried it yet, will try next time I can though, may be awhil, I'll let you know)

Comment: testing this weekend, ill let you know. i got the date file

Comment: Great! Let me know how it goes.

Comment: tried it, didn't seem to work though, when i plugged it into my pc, it showed the files all there, but when i went to copy it over, it said that there were no save data files on the USB Drive. any other ideas

Comment: @Starrfiveo - did you ever get this to work?

Comment: no, when i attempted to move it, it wouldnt let me as it said it was owned by a different PSN account, osrry @camelCase